# What is the limit as $x \to 0$ of the following expression?

Tags: real-analysis, definition, limits-without-lhopital

How to calculate the limit without using L'hopital's rule:
$$\mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\mathrm{cos} x \,\mathrm{cos}2x \,\cdots \mathrm{cos}nx}{x^{2}}\;\;?$$

Comment: Can we try using the Maclaurin expansion of cos(nx)?

Comment: @Ishraaq Parvez  Can I use some elementary methods?

Comment: Can you do it for $n=1$, Chouchou?

Comment: Hi there! I'm more than happy to give you a hand, but I want to (1) avoid writing a solution that contains "redundant" details (e.g. repeating a part of the solution process you've already made progress on and/or clearly understand), and (2) avoid revealing the answer to a homework problem unless I know you've put some effort into solving it. Could you be kind enough to show how you've attempted to attack the problem?

Comment: Yes,I can@Gerry Myerson:
$$\mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\mathrm{cos}x}{x^{2}}=\mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2\mathrm{sin}^{2}(\frac{x}{2})}{x^{2}}=\mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2(\frac{x}{2})^{2}}{x^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Hi Alann Rosas,I've tried some elementary methods.For example,the mathematical induction:
$$\mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\mathrm{cos}x\mathrm{cos}2x\cdots \mathrm{cos}nx}{x^{2}}=\mathrm{lim}_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\mathrm{cos}x\mathrm{cos}2x\cdots \mathrm{cos}(n-1)x}{x^{2}} \frac{1-\mathrm{cos}x\mathrm{cos}2x\cdots \mathrm{cos}nx}{1-\mathrm{cos}x\mathrm{cos}2x\cdots \mathrm{cos}(n-1)x}$$
However I met difficult when dealing with the second term at the right size.

Comment: Why not to use the multiple angle formula and induction ?

Comment: A TeX tip: write `\lim` and `\cos` istead of using `\mathrm`.

Comment: Thanks!@Hans Lundmark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hint for how to do it without Maclaurin expansion:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1-\cos x \cos 2x \cdots \cos nx}{x^{2}}
&
= \frac{1-\cos nx \, \bigl( 1 - 1 + \cos x \cdots \cos (n-1)x \bigr)}{x^{2}}
\\ &
= n^2 \cdot \underbrace{\frac{1-\cos nx}{(nx)^2}}_{\to 1/2} + \underbrace{\strut \cos nx}_{\to 1}  \cdot \underbrace{\frac{1-\cos x \cdots \cos (n-1)x}{x^{2}}}_{\to \, \cdots \, ?} 
\end{split}
$$
Can you continue from there?

Comment: Hi Hans!Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've solve this problem with similar methods:
Suppose that when $n=k$:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\cos{x}\cos{2x}\cdots \cos{kx}}{x^{2}}=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1}{12}$$
When it comes to situation $n=k+1$:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\cos{x}\cos{2x}\cdots \cos{(k+1)x}}{x^{2}}\\
=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\cos{x}\cos{2x}\cdots \cos{kx}}{x^{2}}+\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\cos{x} \cdots \cos{kx}\cdot \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos{(k+1)x}}{x^{2}}\\
=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{12}+1 \cdot \frac{(k+1)^{2}}{2}\\
=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{12}$$
Thus,the answer is $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{gather}
The\ Maclaurin\ expansion\ of\ \cos nx\ is\\
\cos nx=1-\frac{n^{2} x^{2}}{2!} +\frac{n^{4} x^{4}}{4!} +... \notag\\
Now, \notag\\
\cos x\cdotp \cos 2x=\left( 1-\frac{x^{2}}{2!} +...\right)\left( 1-\frac{2^{2} x^{2}}{2!} +..\right) \notag\\
=1-\frac{\left( 1^{2} +2^{2}\right)}{2!} x^{2} +.... \notag\\
Similarly,\ \cos x\cdotp \cos 2x\cdotp \cos 3x=\left( 1-\frac{\left( 1^{2} +2^{2}\right)}{2!} x^{2} +....\right)\left( 1-\frac{( 3x)^{2}}{2!} +..\right) \notag\\
=1-\frac{\left( 1^{2} +2^{2} +3^{2}\right) x^{2}}{2!} +... \notag\\
where\ ...\ denotes\ terms\ that\ are\ higher\ powers\ of\ x\ ( than\ 2) , \notag\\
denoted\ below\ by\ O\left( x^{4}\right) \notag\\
In\ general, \notag\\
\cos x\cos 2x\cdotp \cdotp \cdotp \cos nx=1-\frac{\left( 1^{2} +2^{2} +3^{2} +...n^{2}\right)}{2!} x^{2} +O\left( x^{4}\right) \notag\\
1-\cos x\cos 2x\cdotp \cdotp \cdotp \cos nx=\frac{\left( 1^{2} +2^{2} +3^{2} +...n^{2}\right)}{2!} x^{2} -O\left( x^{4}\right) \notag\\
\frac{1-\cos x\cos 2x\cdotp \cdotp \cdotp \cos nx}{x^{2}} \notag\\
=\frac{\frac{\left( 1^{2} +2^{2} +3^{2} +...n^{2}\right)}{2!} x^{2} -O\left( x^{4}\right)}{x^{2}} \notag\\
=\frac{\left( 1^{2} +2^{2} +3^{2} +...n^{2}\right)}{2!} -O\left( x^{2}\right) \notag\\
Now, \notag\\
\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos x\cos 2x\cdotp \cdotp \cdotp \cos nx}{x^{2}} =\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left( 1^{2} +2^{2} +3^{2} +...n^{2}\right)}{2!} -O\left( x^{2}\right) \notag\\
=\frac{\left( 1^{2} +2^{2} +3^{2} +...n^{2}\right)}{2!} \notag\\
 \notag\\
 \notag\\
 \notag
\end{gather}
Can you complete the answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot and I get the answer is $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}$
However I have to find some elementary methods because my teacher has not taught the maclaurin expansion.

Comment: @Chouchou Can you state what methods are allowed? Ishraaq asked in the comment, and you ignored them, which isn't very nice for someone that's helping you.

Comment: @Calvin Lin  I'm sorry! It's my fault that I didn't what methods are allowed.I'll pay attention next time.Now I've found a way to solve this problem.Thanks a lot anyway@Ishraaq Parvez